There is no audio coming from my TV speakers
I recently connected my AirPods to my Apple TV, which worked great. However, I cannot seem to disconnect my AirPods, and I can now not hear any audio output from my TV speakers themselves.
(Refer to Image) If you look at the audio output section, you’ll see that I’ve already attempted to switch back to my TV speakers, but I cannot hear audio from my TV. On an added note, the bottom left corner says that there is an ‘audio system’ connected to the TV. However, I have already disconnected all devices from bluetooth.
I have tried all the usual fixes like restarting and even resetting my Apple TV. Has anybody else experienced the same issue?

